# Inverting a Scrabble letter score map

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, interview-questions

Question:

> The old system stored a list of letters per score:
>
> 1 point: "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "L", "N", "R", "S", "T",
>
> 2 points: "D", "G",
>
> 3 points: "B", "C", "M", "P",
>
> 4 points: "F", "H", "V", "W", "Y",
>
> 5 points: "K",
>
> 8 points: "J", "X",
>
> 10 points: "Q", "Z",
>
> The shiny new scrabble system instead stores the score per letter, which makes it much faster and easier to calculate the score for a word. It also stores the letters in lower-case regardless of the case of the input letters:
>
> "a" is worth 1 point.
>
> "b" is worth 3 points.
>
> "c" is worth 3 points.
>
> "d" is worth 2 points.
>
> Etc.
>
> Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to write a program that transforms the legacy data format to the shiny new format.

Code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class Etl extends AbstractModule {
  public Map transform(Map<Integer, List<String>> oldData) {
    Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry: oldData.entrySet()) {
      for(String chr: entry.getValue()) {
       items.put(chr.toLowerCase(), entry.getKey()); 
      }
    }
    return items;
  }
}
```

Can the above code be made more readable and optimized?

Comment: related: [answer on how to invert a map](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7147052) on [so], with a generic version and one with streams.

Comment: Start commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to improve readability is through the naming of your variables.

- `oldData` can be called something like `pointsMap` or `pointsGroups`
- `items` can be called `result` or `characterPoints`
- `entry` can be called `pointGroup`
- `chr` can be called `character` (and would as the other answer suggests be better of as a `Character` and not `String`)

Additionally, your class is called `Etl` which I just have no clue what that's supposed to mean. I'm also not sure why it `extends AbstractModule`.

Also, your `transform` method can be `static`

Answer (score 2):

The two things I would change:

- The `Map` you're returning should have type parameters.
- The key is best to be a `Character` rather than a `String`.

Other than that, I don't see much more to it than what you've got there already.